# Changing font color based on color at cursor position in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like some help with creating macro to change color of all text of the same color in Excel sheet, based on font color near cursor position inside cell or selected text fragment (cell will have multiple color text).

To clarify question a bit more: im looking for method to get font color value into vba script, where color must be somehow selected by user from cell that will contain text in several random colors. For example user double clicking cell and placing text cursor inside text with certain color or selecting fragment of text with certain color. 
Or another alternative to create menu with all text colors used on sheet and let user click on colors he wants to change.

Comment: Can you explain a little clearer and post some code that you've attempted.

Comment: Target.Font.ColorIndex

Comment: This is non-trivial, but start here for a color picker - http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/1691.html

Comment: You could use `.FindFormat` to do this maybe